# Parse data through API with useEffect for Algolia

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, algolia

I need to parse stock data through YahooFinance Stocks API, using RapidAPI here how it would look like as an example response.

> https://rapidapi.com/integraatio/api/yahoofinance-stocks1/

The error I am getting is:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'data' before
> initialization

```
"results":1294 items
[100 items
0:{4 items
"exchangeCode":"NMS"
"symbol":"1"
"companyName":"1"
"industryOrCategory":"N/A"
}
1:{...}4 items
2:{4 items
"exchangeCode":"NMS"
"symbol":"AAON"
"companyName":"AAON, Inc."
"industryOrCategory":"Industrials"
}
3:{4 items
"exchangeCode":"NMS"
"symbol":"AAPL"
"companyName":"Apple Inc."
"industryOrCategory":"Technology"
}
]




useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "stock-market-data.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": APIKEY,
      },
    };

    const fetchStocks = async () => {
        const json = JSON.parse(data);

  const results = Object.keys(json["results"]);

  const stockInfo = results.map(
    (result) =>
      (result = {
        result,
        close: String(json["results"][result]),
      })
  );

      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "https://stock-market-data.p.rapidapi.com/market/exchange/nasdaq",
        config
      );
      data.forEach((results) => {
        results.objectID = results.length;
      });
      setStocks(data);
    };
    fetchStocks();
  }, [])
```

Comment: `const json = JSON.parse(data);`  is this a mistake?

Comment: if I don't have that then this error occurs: TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Comment: are you sure data is an array

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a marshaling issue in your Javascript more than an Algolia issue. Perhaps because the `await axios.get()` needs to be in an async function per https://stackabuse.com/making-asynchronous-http-requests-in-javascript-with-axios/

> To use the async/await syntax, we need to wrap the axios.get() function call within an async function

Curious the contents of `data` before and after the `data.forEach()` (also could that be a `map`?)